# WhatsApp won't download on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

My new iPhone 7 was accidentally wiped by our IT dept. I have managed to restore everything except WhatsApp, which is just showing a cloud with down arrow. I have deleted it from my iCloud drive and rebooted the phone but still no joy. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I think Your problem description is not clear.
As I can possibly imagine, the downloading process is stuck.
First of all, make sure that Your Wi-Fi or Network is connected, then make sure that You have deleted stuck WhatsApp from Your iPhone home screen. Then open AppStore app and download new WhatsApp app. It should work.